# Designing User & its Sub User Database Diagram Problem

Tags: oracle, database-design, erd, sqlplus, database-diagrams

1. There are some business category e.g. Travel Agency, Hotel, Car Rental etc.
2. Roles:

- Management rolesSuper Admin, Staff
- Customer side roles are Owner, admin and sales counter
- May be etc. customer side roles will be added

3. Status i.e. On-Hold, Active, In-Active, Blocked, Deleted etc.
4. Scenario:

- Each user in the database has its role and status with other credentials
- Super Admin or Staff creates a customer (USER) with category e.g. "Travel Agency" and provide owner details
- Now this Travel Agency (USER) has its own SUB_USERS that may be one or many

Now I am confused between user and sub users. 
The work that I done so far is as following in shape of ERD:
[image]

Please put me on the right path as to how can I create a USER with its SUB USERS?

Thanks in anticipation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just get rid of the `main_user` and `sub_user` tables and have a nullable field on the `users` table called `parent_user_id`. Then you can use a **self-join** on `users.parent_user_id = users.user_id` to get all the sub-users for a given Travel Agency. (When the `parent_user_id` field is null, that's a Travel Agency.)

Comment: you mean I keep user_id as it is and add a new column parent_user_id?

Comment: Thanks J.D. Self-Join helped me

Comment: @Murteza Sorry just seeing your replies now, yes keep the `user_id` column as is and add an additional column `parent_user_id`. No problem!